# Android web services -  XML-RPC Client

Tags: android, web-services

I want to implement XML-RPC web service in Android.

Server I will create in PHP, but I need XML-RPC Android client.

Can someone recommend me any source code, tutorial or example?

I try with http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/web-services-an-xml-rpc-client-for-android-t646.html but I receive error when importing jar files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link in a Google search on:

android xml-rpc

is [this open source project](http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/).